# Unable to connect to MYSQL using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I was trying to connect to my localhost:3306 using NodeJS, and below is the code for the same

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'test',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("error occured")
    }
    else {
        console.log("connection created")
    }
})
```

On running the js file, I am getting **error occured** and not able to print **connection created**. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: What exact error did you get? Can you show the whole error message in the post?

Comment: code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
  errno: 1251,
  sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
  sqlState: '08004',
  fatal: true